# What type of singularity does g(z) have at z=0? And what is the res(g(z),0)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

For nonnegative integer k, the Bessel function of order k is an
entire function defined by $$J_k(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{k+2n}}{n!(k+n)!2^{k+2n}}$$ What type of singularity does $$g(z)=j_k(\frac{1}{z})$$ have at z=0? And What is the res(g(z),0)?

**my attempt:** It has an isolated singularity because there are no other singularities around it and also the fact that its a function of 1/z is at 0.

As for the finding residue,

$$ g(z)=j_k(\frac{1}{z}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{-k-2n}}{n!(k+n)!2^{k+2n}} $$
then I sub it into,

$$ \oint_{\gamma}^\ g(z)  dz=2\pi i\sum res(g(z),0)$$

to get,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}^\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{-k-2n}}{n!(k+n)!2^{k+2n}}  dz=\sum res(g(z),0)$$

And I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: The residue of a function at a point $p$ is the same as the coefficient of $(z-p)^{-1}$ in the Laurent series about that point.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;2n+k=1\iff n=\frac{1-k}2\;$ . Observe this is possible iff $\;k=1\;$ , as it is given that $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ , so the residue is zero for $\;\Bbb N\ni k\ge2\;$ , whereas for $\;k=1\;$ we have to take $\;n=0\;$ and the coefficient is

$$a_0=\frac{(-1)^0}{0!(0+1)!2^{1+0}}=\frac12$$